# What should be the syntax to run a cronjob every Friday @startup?

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run a python script every friday at startup, but can't seem to find the correct syntax. I want it like this so that i can make sure it runs on friday, otherwise at a specific time I might have my laptop turned off sometimes.

I'm on Linux using ubuntu 19.04.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`0 0 * * FRI` for every Friday at 0:00 am

```
0 0 * * FRI /home/user/myscript.sh
```